# Is there an "adb" command to clear default of a specific app?

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

There is an Android API to clear default of the current app (I think by just disable&enable the activity that handles the intent), and the user can manage any app and clear the default of it, but is there also a way to clear the default of a specific app, using **adb** command ?

Comment: See this http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/142880/setting-default-applications-through-adb

Comment: @Tigger I didn't ask about removal. This will reset the entire app. Plus, this method doesn't work for system apps.

Comment: @VivekMishra So you say I could disable&enable the app. But I think it will cause some side effects no ? If the app is currently running, it will stop it.Maybe it will even do more harm.  At least, I think it's better to disable&enable only the component that is responsible of the intent. Isn't there another way?

Comment: Try this command - `adb shell dumpsys package preferred-xml`, maybe its output can help you.

Comment: @TDG This is for getting information about the app (which is nice to know, btw, thanks, wonder if it's available via API too), but it doesn't show how to do a clear-default for the given app.

Comment: @Onik Some apps can handle specific intents, so the user can choose which app to handle which. The user can also reset the default app, by going to its app-info screen and choose "clear defaults". Here's an example: http://www.greenbot.com/article/2151008/how-to-set-and-clear-default-applications-in-android.html

Comment: @Onik That's how it's called "clear defaults". Calling it something else would be confusing.

Comment: OK I created a new request for Google on this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=233091